# Looping text print on an LCD screen using Python API

Tags: python

I've connected a 20*4 LCD screen on my Raspberry Pi. It works.

Now I want to screen several sentences and loop them

Thanks to Hapex I 've a code that works but not exactly as I want. I can't pause and clear time to time

Here is the actual code :

```
  def typewriter_like(sentence, lcd_line, delay=0.7):
      for i,letter in enumerate(sentence):
      lcd_byte(lcd_line, LCD_CMD)
          lcd_string(sentence[:i+1],1)
      time.sleep(delay)

  mots = (("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLES", "EXAMPLESS", "EXAMPLESSS"),
          ("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"),
          ("LULU", "FIFI", "RIRI", "TATA"))
  lcds = (0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4)
  list(zip(mots,lcds))
  [(('EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLES', 'EXAMPLESS', 'EXAMPLESSS'),128),(('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE','FOUR'),192),(('LULU', 'FIFI', 'RIRI', 'TATA'),148)]

  while True:
    for mot in mots:
        for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
            typewriter_like(word, lcd)
    time.sleep(10)

    for lcd in lcds:
            lcd_byte(lcd, LCD_CMD)
            lcd_string("",2)

    time.sleep(4)
```

What I want is to pause the first 4 words... Then erase everything (all cleared) before print the 4 next words

EXAMPLE
EXAMPLES
EXAMPLESS
EXAMPLESSS

stay printed for 10 seconds
Then all cleared

ONE
TWO
THREE
FOUR ...

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have with your second code is a misunderstanding of the line `for mot, lcd in zip(mots, lcds):`. You are zipping the whole tuples with the words together with the hex numbers, but you want to zip each word with one number.

Open your python interpreter and see the result of:

```
>>> mots = (("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLES", "EXAMPLESS", "EXAMPLESSS"),
         ("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"),
       ("LULU", "FIFI", "RIRI", "TATA"))
>>> lcds = (0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4)
>>> list(zip(mots, lcds))
[(('EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLES', 'EXAMPLESS', 'EXAMPLESSS'), 128), (('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR'), 192), (('LULU', 'FIFI', 'RIRI', 'TATA'), 148)]
```

The solution is to loop over `mots` and in a nested loop over the zip.

```
for mot in mots:
    for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
        typewriter_like(word, lcd)
```

---

The first argument of your function `typewriter_like` should be a string and not a tuple.

To pause the display for 10 seconds after the current 4 lines are printed modify your loop to the following:

```
for mot in mots:
    for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
        typewriter_like(word, lcd)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I've tried that and edited my post... But still an error

Comment: @NicoLune You are doing `typewriter_like(mot, lcd)` but it should be `typewriter_like(word, lcd)`, notice the variable `word` instead of `mot` as first argument. And there is a second error: `zip(mot, lcds)` instead of `zip(mots, lcds)`. Notice the singular instead of plural

Comment: It works (thanks) but I'd like to pause each 4 word... "EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLES", "EXAMPLESS", "EXAMPLESSS"... Pause... Then everything is cleared... "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"... PAuse... Cleared... And so one... Is this possible ? Could someone put me on the right tracks

Comment: @NicoLune I edited my answer and added the code I think should work

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any difference : words are still looping without pause and without been cleared before next occurence

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a problem with indentation? 
The while loop and the def typewriter_like where on the same level, so typewriter_like got called recursively.

```
def typewriter_like(sentence, lcd_line, delay=0.7):
      for i,letter in enumerate(sentence):
      lcd_byte(lcd_line, LCD_CMD)
         lcd_string(sentence[:i+1],1)
      time.sleep(delay)

mots = (("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLES", "EXAMPLESS", "EXAMPLESSS"),
         ("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"),
         ("LULU", "FIFI", "RIRI", "TATA"))
lcds = (0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4)

while True:
  for mot, lcd in zip(mots, lcds):
      typewriter_like(mot, lcd)
      time.sleep(10)
```